# Clarify, please, specification - 14.9.6 Reference type equality operators

Tags: c#, .net

There is always something to learn. =)

```
class My
{
}
```

this is compiled:

```
void Main()
{
    My s = new My();
    IList<My> my = null;
    Console.WriteLine(my == s);
}
```

and this is not:

```
void Main()
{
    My s = new My();
    List<My> my = null;
    Console.WriteLine(my == s);
}
```

The whole difference in the `class vs interface`.

Here is what [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) says:

The operators return the result of comparing the two references for equality or non-equality.

There are special rules for determining when a reference type equality operator is applicable.

For an equality-expression with operands of type A and B, define A0 as follows:

- If A is a type parameter known to be a reference type (§25.7), let A0 be the effective base class of A.
- Otherwise, if A is an interface type, a delegate type, an array type, a class type, or the null type (§11.2.7), let A0 be the same as A. **(our case in both cases, isn't it?)**
- Otherwise, no reference type equality operator is applicable.

Now define A1 as follows:

- If A0 is an interface type **(first case?)**, a delegate type, System.Delegate, or string, let A1 be object **(but why?)**.
- Otherwise, if A0 is an array type, let A1 be System.Array.
- Otherwise, A0 is the null type or a class type and let A1 be the same as A0. **(second case?)**

Define B0 and B1 in the same manner.

Now determine if any reference type equality operators are applicable
as follows:

1. If both of the types A and B are the null type, then overload
   resolution is not performed and the result is a constant true or
   false, as specified in §14.9.
2. Otherwise, if A is the null type, then the reference type equality operator for B1 is applicable. If B is a type parameter and at
   runtime the type parameter is a non-nullable value type, the result
   of the operation is false. If B is a type parameter and at runtime
   the type parameter is a nullable type or reference type, the result
   is as if the operand of type B is boxed and then compared to null.
3. Otherwise, if B is the null type, then the reference type equality operator for A1 is applicable. If A is a type parameter and at
   runtime the type parameter is a non-nullable value type, the result
   of the operation is false. If A is a type parameter and at runtime
   the type parameter is a nullable type or reference type, the result
   is as if the operand of type A is boxed and then compared to null.
4. Otherwise, if either A or B is a type parameter that is not known to be a reference type (§25.7), then no reference type equality
   operator is applicable.
5. Otherwise, if there is no identity or reference conversion (implicit or explicit) from A0 to B0 or no identity or reference
   conversion (implicit or explicit) from B0 to A0, then no reference
   type equality operator is applicable.
6. Otherwise, if there is an identity or implicit reference conversion from A1 to B1, then the reference type equality operator
   for B1 is applicable.
7. Otherwise, if there is an implicit reference conversion from B1 to A1, then the reference type equality operator for A1 is applicable.
8. Otherwise, no reference type equality operator is applicable.

So it tries  `class vs object` comparison in the first case and `class 1 vs class 2` - in the second.

Why are these rules as they are? Just do not see the underlying reasons. Why not explicit cast is required? What are the implications?

Comment: The runtime type of the object _may_ implement the interface so the compiler has to allow for the possibility of such a comparison. In this particular example, we see that `My` implements no interfaces. But that's not to say anything derived from it cannot. You'll see that if you made the `My` class `sealed`, it will result in an error. I suspect this is part of the reason.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, I though of this possibility, but didn't check with 'sealed'. But I still do not understand. If we cast interface explicitly we can get the call to overloaded `==` operator. But in case of assuming interface is an object won't we always have just a reference compare?